# What is the action command name activated by mouse hovering over some piece of code?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, ideavim, jetbrains-rider

I would like to create a vim shortcut with the action activated by hovering the mouse over some piece of code (compiler errors to get its description, suggestions, functions to get its parameters etc).

Is there any mapped action to it? I was not able to find what I am looking for in `:actionlist`.

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Comment: I have created new shortcuts using `ParameterInfo` to get the paremeter list and `ShowErrorDescription` to get an error description but still have not found any solution to the question above.

Comment: HoverDoc https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/documentation-provider.html#implement-additional-functionality ? But it is not an Action

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the popup is actually a result of two separate actions: "Error description" and "Quick documentation". Unfortunately, there isn no action that shows both, as far as I know